# Why would someone with 1 question with 1 upvote be considered a "Top network User"?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, top-users

I just noticed that on the Hot Questions page there's a widget for "Top Network Users".

I clicked on the very first user on the list (Ali on Blender.SE) to see who it was (I was kind of expecting Jon Skeet's alias or something)... and the user had exactly ONE answer, with ONE upvote (and reputation of 6) on the Blender site. They aren't a part of any other sites.

How can someone with those stats be possibly considered a "Top Network User"?

I realize that it may be somehow linked to the list of Hot Questions, but if the question's BEST answerer is at 1 upvote, that question shouldn't be on the Hot List (or the asker, if the question itself has only 1 upvote). And if that question has better answers, that user should not be incldued into Top Users list.

Comment: Read it like: `(top network) users`, i.e. random users of the best network. _Bit_ of a stretch, but works out.

Answer (score 7):

There's a short blurb below that title:

> These users asked or provided top answers for the posts on this page

So it has nothing to do with them being "top network users" - it is just a list of authors for the hot questions seen to the left. Each user should correspond to each question going in order down the list.

Comment: I guess the title of that sidebar could be made a bit more descriptive.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - yeah, **that**.