# Having two questions from the same site on the same page of the Hot Network Questions list makes only one profile show up

Tags: support, hot-questions

I currently have two questions ([1](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23861/how-can-i-make-a-shared-world-less-restrictive), [2](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23765/how-can-i-make-my-languages-structurally-less-like-english)) on the front page of the Hot Network Questions list, both from Worldbuilding:

[image]

Only my profile picture for the first one shows up; it isn't there for the second one. I'm simply skipped over.

Comment: The right hand sidebar is for 'Top Network Users'

Comment: @HackerKarma Ah, so it's only supposed to show once?

Comment: I mean to say _unique_ (too late to edit) user profile in the 'Top Network Users' section. Added answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the number of 'Hot' questions (30 count) on the left and the 'Top Network Users' (29 count) in the right hand sidebar panel, I can say that *user* profile is listed only **once** (making it unique) even if he/she has multiple questions in the 'Hot' list.

As the 'Hot' lists gets updated, I'm also [attaching the PDF](http://docdro.id/4w8EySX) file (generated few mins. after OP post submission) for the cross reference.

On the side note for my comments about '**Top Network Users**' as I found the description ("These users asked or provided top answers for the posts on this page") is quite confusing. Upon doing little bit more research I found of following things:

Moderator animuson's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246174/why-would-someone-with-1-question-with-1-upvote-be-considered-a-top-network-use/246175#246175):

> So it has nothing to do with them being "top network users" - it is
>   just a list of authors for the hot questions seen to the left. Each
>   user should correspond to each question going in order down the list.

But the user corresponding has an *exception* when there are multiple posts from the same user e.g. OP's given example.

Moderator Oded's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258499/sidebar-of-hnq-shows-only-the-users-who-asked-the-questions-but-not-those-who-a#comment842439_258499):

> The list is limited in number - doesn't mean that answerers never show
>   up there. IIRC there is a bias towards askers.

Moderator Anna Lear's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236473/confusing-wording-for-top-network-users-on-stack-exchange-front-page#comment775270_236473):

> Not entirely sold on the proposed wording, but I agree that what we
>   got now is clunky at best.